# How can I join tables with different data types using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

With the situation of using Entity Framework,I want to join tables with two field in same value,but the fields are identified with different data types. For example,there is a field which the data type is 'Guid',but in another table the associated field is 'string' type. I am confused to achieve the goal. Can somebody give me some ideas.Here are my codes, emps.EmpGuid is a 'Guid' data type and flowCode.Object is a string:

```
DbSet<tb_Emp_Manager_Zbdl> dbEmp = zbdlcontext.Emp_Manager;
DbSet<Tb_Corp_CompanyInfo_Zbdl> dbCompany = zbdlcontext.Corp_CompanyInfos;
DbSet<Tb_FlowCode_Zbdl> dbFlowCode = zbdlcontext.FlowCodes;
DbSet<Tb_Emp_Post_Zbdl> dbEmpPost = zbdlcontext.Emp_Post;
var query = from emps in dbEmp
            join companies in dbCompany on emps.CorpGuid equals companies.CorpUserGuid
            join flowCode in dbFlowCode on new { EmpGuid = emps.EmpGuid.ToString(), AreaCode = areaCode } equals new { EmpGuid = flowCode.ObjectId, AreaCode = flowCode.AreaCode } into jFlowCodes
            from flowCodes in jFlowCodes.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join post in dbEmpPost on emps.EmpGuid equals post.EmpGuid into jPosts
            from posts in jPosts.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new tb_Emp_Manager()
                       {
                            EmpGuid = emps.EmpGuid,
                            AreaCode = emps.AreaCode,
                            FlowCode = flowCodes.FlowCode,
                            corpName = companies.CorpName
                       };
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: If flowCode.ObjectId is a string that is the equivalent to Guid.ToString(), this should work. What is the error / incorrect behavior you are getting?